# SQLAlchemy migration table already exist

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate, sqlalchemy-migrate

I just got started using `flask-migrate` and I encounter some problems with it. 
In order to get myself familiarized with it, I started a new project with a mock MySQL database.

I run the migration as following

```
 export FLASK_APP=run.py
 flask db init
 flask db migrate
 flask db upgrade
```

and it throws this error:

```
   ...
  File "c:\users\terkea\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1050, "Table 'user' already exists")
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE `User` (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        public_id VARCHAR(50),
        name VARCHAR(50),
        password VARCHAR(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE (name),
        UNIQUE (public_id)
)

]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: The normal order of operations is to add/change a model, then do the `flask db migrate` (to have migration build the python-side code necessary to migrate the schema to match the new models, then `flask db upgrade`to apply that to to the schema. If you change the schema by hand, that confuses the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to

1. get rid of  `__tablename__` from all my models
2. Drop all the tables from the database before running the migration